# Calling a method on initial state with AASM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is it possible to invoke a method when the initial state is entered when using the [AASM](http://github.com/rubyist/aasm/tree/master) Gem? I'd like the `spam_check` method to get called when a comment is submitted, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AASM

  aasm_column :state
  aasm_initial_state :submitted
  aasm_state :submitted, :enter => :spam_check
  aasm_state :approved
  aasm_state :rejected

  aasm_event :ham do
    transitions :to => :approved, :from => [:submitted, :rejected]
  end

  aasm_event :spam do
    transitions :to => :rejected, :from => [:submitted, :approved]
  end

  def spam_check
    # Mark the comment as spam or ham...
  end
end
```

Comment: I think your :ham and :spam are reversed.

Comment: A comment starts as submitted and if it's ham then it becomes approved, if spam it becomes rejected. However, approved comments can also be marked as spam etc. if the auto spam checker got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, that since the spam checking is taking place just before the initial state is set, your :spam and :ham transitions can't be executed, since the :from condition says the state should be :submitted, :rejected or :approved (but in the fact, it's nil). Initial state is set on `before_validation_on_create` callback, so what about trying it like this?

```
after_validation_on_create :spam_check

aasm_event :spam_check do
  transitions :to => :approved, :from => [:submitted, :rejected], :guard => Proc.new {|c| !c.spam?} 
  transitions :to => :rejected, :from => [:submitted, :approved], :guard => 'spam?'
end

def spam?
  # your spam checking routine
end
```

This should fire the `spam_check` event after the `initial_state` was set and will set ste state to either `:approved` or :`rejected`.

Comment: Thanks. I realised after I posted the question that it makes sense to only check if the comment is spam after it passes validation.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the initialize method?, it's not as self-documenting but should work.